# TypeORM conditional nullable?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am developing a log in system in NestJS using TypeORM and Postgres.
In my login options, I propose the user to use a couple email / password or to use an OAuth authentication. But once an account is created, they are not mutually exclusive (a user can have an email + password and a Google account attached to his account, for example).

Therefore, I would like to make the password OR the OAuthLogin nullable, but at least one of them should never be nullable.

Is it possible to achieve this with TypeORM ?

```js
@Entity()
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    public email: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    @Exclude()
    public password?: string;

    @JoinColumn()
    @OneToMany(() => OAuthLogin, (provider: OAuthLogin) => provider.user, {
        cascade: true,
    })
    public oAuthLogins: OAuthLogin[];
}

export default User;
```

(P. S.: for my current code, I chose to make the password only nullable...)

Comment: I don't know about typeorm, but in postgres you need to make both columns nullable and add a `CHECK` constraint on the table with [`num_nonnulls(password, o_auth_logins) >= 1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE) or something similar.

Comment: I'm looking into this: there seems to be a Check decorator I can do some verification with, but I don't find how to check if the relation exists... `@Check(`"password" IS NOT NULL OR "oAuthLogins" IS NOT NULL`)` isn't working because Postgres looks for a oAuthLogins property instead of a relation.

Comment: Oh, I missed that it's a relation as you spoke of "nullable". No, you can't do that with a check constraint. If you wanted to do this on a database level, you'd need a trigger.

Comment: Well it's not really the relation that should be nullable, but rather the data at the other end. Handling relation data is the one thing ORMs aren't good for and therefore, make it a bit more complicated ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, not at the TypeORM level. However, you can achieve this in your application code using the [`ValidateIf`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) decorator from `class-validator`:

```js
@Column({ nullable: true })
@Exclude()
@IsNotEmpty()
@ValidateIf(u => !u.oAuthLogins || u.oAuthLogins.length === 0)
public password?: string;

@JoinColumn()
@IsArray()
@ValidateIf(u => !u.password)
@OneToMany(() => OAuthLogin, (provider: OAuthLogin) => provider.user, {
cascade: true,
})
public oAuthLogins?: OAuthLogin[];
```

Elsewhere in your application:

```js
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
...
validate(user)
```

If this entity is crossing a controller, you can also use NestJS's `ValidationPipe` to [enforce this at the controller or application](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) level:

```js
// main.ts
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
```