# TypeORM using SoftRemove and Unique decorator

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, soft-delete

Help me please resolve next issue. I use NestJS + TypeORM softRemove/softDelete for delete records. And I want to apply @Unique decorator only for undeleted records.
My remove method like:

```
public async delete(id: number): Promise<UpdateResult> {
   return await this.repo.softDelete(id);
}
```

In Entity will be perfect something like:

```
@Entity('role')
@Unique('UQ_TITLE', ['title', 'deletedDate IS NULL'])//IS NULL not supported there :(
export class Role {

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })//may be exists some expression for column settings
    title: string;

    @DeleteDateColumn({ select: false })
    deletedDate?: Date;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. You have basically two options: [Application checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849855/typeorm-conditional-nullable) or [Partial Unique Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236365/postgresql-conditionally-unique-constraint).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to create other check instead above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality you need by using a custom index instead of the `@Unique` decorator.

```
import { Entity, Column, DeleteDateColumn, Index } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('role')
@Index('UQ_TITLE', ['title'], { unique: true, where: '(deletedDate IS NULL)' })
export class Role {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })
  title: string;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ select: false })
  deletedDate?: Date;
}
```